# Noblesse oblige loanword in German

Tags: loanword

*Noblesse oblige*, how would I say it in German? I'm guessing *Adelpflicht* or *Adel verpflichtet* but I've only seen this in one dictionary. Nothing online seems to help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The German version of this phrase is:

> Adel verpflichtet

But you quite often also can hear the untranslated french phrase in German conversations too.

Comment: I would go even further and say that the "German" version is to leave it French, and you might also hear this real German version sometimes.

Comment: To my American ears, if it's *Adel verpflictet* it should be *zum Adel verpflichtet*, i.e., "to nobility obligated", but of course German surprises me everyday. . . .

Comment: @147pm No "zum Adel verpflichtet" means something entirely different. "Adel verpflichtet" means nobility comes with obligations, "zum Adel verpflichtet" would mean you are obligated to (always) be nobility, but also somewhat sounds like you were recruited to become nobility.

Comment: And "Noblesse oblige" also literally means "nobility obliges".

Comment: So yes, *Adel verpflichtet* means "nobility obliges," not "noble obligation".